# Java; Swapping two elements in a DoublyLinkedList without changing the data without collections

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Okay, so I'm trying to swap two elements in a doubly linked list without altering the data and without using collections. Here's what I have so far;

```
package q2b;

public class DoublyLinkedList {
    static Node first;
    static Node last;
    
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }
    
    public void display() {
        Node current = first;

        if(first == null) {
            System.out.println("List is empty.");
        }
        System.out.print("Nodes: ");
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data+", ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public void add(int x) {
        if (last==null) {
            Node temp = new Node(x);
            last = temp;
            first = temp;
        }
        
        else {
            Node temp = new Node(x);
            last.next = temp;
            temp.prev = last;
            last = temp;
        }
    }
    
    public Pair find(int x, int y) {
        Node n1 = null;
        Node n2 = null;
        Node temp = first;
        
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.data == x) {
                n1 = temp;
            }
            else if (temp.data == y) {
                n2 = temp;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return new Pair(n1,n2);
    }
    
    public void swap(int x, int y) {
        if (first == null || first.next == null || x == y) {
            return;
        }
        
        Pair p = find(x,y);
        
        Node n1 = p.first;
        Node n2 = p.second;
        
        if (n1==first) {
            first = n2;
        }
        else if (n2 == first) {
            first = n1;
        }
        
        if (n1 == last) {
            last = n2;
        }
        else if (n2 == last) {
            last = n1;
        }
        
        Node temp;
        temp = n1.next;
        n1.next = n2.next;
        n2.next = temp;
        
        if (n1.next != null) {
            n1.next.prev = n1;
        }
        if (n2.next != null) {
            n2.prev.next = n2;
        }
        
        temp = n1.prev;
        n1.prev = n2.prev;
        n2.prev = temp;
        
        if (n1.prev != null) {
            n1.prev.next = n1;
        }
        if (n2.prev != null) {
            n2.prev.next = n2;
        }
    }
}
```

And my main;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();
        list.add(2);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(10);
        list.display();
        list.swap(6, 8);
        list.display();
    }
}
```

Now when I go to run the code, it just infinitely runs until it crashes. I assume I'm missing something in the swap function that is sending it into a death spiral, but I'm not sure what it is. Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: And if your code is crashing, it is not running infinitely. Edit your question to include the error message and stack trace.

Comment: I can't get to the debugger because when I start it, my IDE locks up and I have to ctrl-alt-delete to exit the program. There is no crash and error message.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Anyway, put a breakpoint near the start, and step after execution hits it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in:

```
if (n2.next != null) {
   n2.prev.next = n2;
}
```

This is because `n1` and `n2` are originally consecutive nodes, which means that the `prev` of `n2` is `n1`. So after you swapped the `next`s of `n1` and `n2` the expression `n2.prev.next = n2` is equal to `n1.next = n2`, which overrides the `n1.next = n2.next` you did a few lines before and points `n1`'s `next` back to `n2` while `n2`'s next is `n1`, so now you have a circle where `n1.next` points to `n2` and `n2.next` points to `n1` - that creates an endless loop when you try to traverse the nodes in `display()` and that's why your code never returns.
One possible solution is to change the if to:

```
if (n2.next != null && n2.prev != n1) {
   n2.prev.next = n2;
}
```

I think you'll have to apply a similar treatment to the other three ifs

Comment: So I should always check to make sure the previous node does not equal the opposite? What about in the last two branches where I'm already dealing with the previous node?

Comment: As I said you'll probably need to augment the condition of all 4 ifs. These two:
        if (n1.next != null) {
            n1.next.prev = n1;
        }
        if (n2.next != null) {
            n2.prev.next = n2;
        }
        
and these two:        
        if (n1.prev != null) {
            n1.prev.next = n1;
        }
        if (n2.prev != null) {
            n2.prev.next = n2;
        }